# changing static tag after collectstatic - django

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I have been working with django for a while now and I am close to deploying it. To collect all the static files at one place, I ran:

```
manage.py collectstatic
```

which got all my static files into the folder I set through STATIC_ROOT.

Do I now have to go through all the html where I had done something like :

```
<script src="{% static "DataManagement/js/main.js" %}"></script>
```

and remove the django tags and set it to something like:

```
<script src="SPECIFIED_DESTINATION_AT_STATIC_ROOT"></script>
```

I am sure that it's cumbersome to do it.

**How can I automatically change from:**

```
<script src="{% static "DataManagement/js/main.js" %}"></script>
```

to

```
<script src="SPECIFIED_DESTINATION_AT_STATIC_ROOT"></script>
```

**after I run collectstatic?**

Comment: No - of course you don't have to do this. Did you read the documentation about [static files](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/static-files/)?

Comment: Can you point me to the right direction?

Comment: You did not say what the problem is :) - From what I see I can just tell you that you *don't* have to touch your templates...

Comment: I changed my post to reflect your concern.

Comment: Is there a reason why you need your static files in the webroot `/` instead of a `/static/` directory? This does not really make sense?

Comment: Does the edit makes it clear?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115866/discussion-between-ohrstrom-and-jack-of-all-trades).